# why map function is not working in monte carlo

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I want to do 1000 times of Monte Carlo simulation of linear regressions and get 1000 estimates:

```
dt <- data.table( x = runif(n,0,1),
                  e = rnorm(n),
                  alpha = runif(n,-100,100))[, y := alpha + beta*x + e][, -c("e","alpha")]
set.seed(872)

map( rep(1:B) , ~lm(y ~ x, data = dt))
```

This works well. But I changed the third line above to

```
dt %>% map( rep(1:B), ~lm(y ~ x, data=. ) )
```

An error occurred. Why did the error occur?

Comment: In your first code chunk, `dt` is a data table with columns in rows. When you use `.` in your second code, it represents an integer between 1 and `B`, which is not defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pipe the input from left-hand side (LHS) is first argument to function on right-hand side (RHS).

So, the code

```
dt %>% map(rep(1:B), ~lm(y ~ x, data=. ))
```

is same as :

```
map(dt, rep(1:B), ~lm(y ~ x, data=. ) )
```

To use pipes here you can wrap the code in `{...}` however, `.` is not the dataframe but the current value from `map`. See for example,

```
map(1:5, ~.)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 4

#[[5]]
#[1] 5
```

You can use an anonymous function in `map` so `p` is the value from `map` and `.` can be referred to as dataframe.

```
dt %>% {map(rep(1:B), function(p) lm(y ~ x, data=. ) )}
```